# Bad arguments error, implementing Numerical Recipes function

Tags: c, function

EDIT: This is a typo error. I wrote `1` one but it should be `l` ell. Thanks everyone!

I hate to ask a n00b question like this on SO, but I would like to write a simple program to check the functions written in Numerical Recipes by Press, Teukolsky, etc. I'm slightly inexperienced using C, so this may be entirely obvious. (Please be patient!)

The function in question is the associated legendre polynomial from the chapter on Special Functions. I have documented this thoroughly in the code below. However, it appears I do not understand how to call a function correctly. When running the program below using `$ ./a.out` after compiling with `gcc program.c`, I get the following error:

```
Run time error....
Bad arguments in routine plgndr
Now exiting the system
```

I'm guessing this is obvious to fix, but so far I haven't quite figured it out. I should better understand C after this question, even if it is not helpful to other SO readers...

The `nrerror` function is a standard of the Numerical Recipes series, which is found in Appendix B. Here is my code (excuse the extensive comments at the beginning):

```
/* Recurrence relation, Legendre polynomial

 Numerical recipes in C, 1992
 Press, Flannery, Teukolsky, Vetterling

 Chapter 6., Special Functions, 
 Section 6.8 Spherical Harmonics, p.252-254

 The Legendre polynomial recurrence relation is written as

 (n+1)*P_{n+1}(x)=(2n+1)*x*P_n(x)-n*P_{n-1}(x)

 float plgndr(int l, int m, float x)
 Computes the associated Legendre polynomial P^m_l(x). Here m and l
 are integers satisfying 0<=m<=l, while x lies in the range
 -1<=x<=1.

 P(0,x) = 1
 P(1,x) = x
 P(n,x) = (2*n-1)/n * x * P(n-1,x) - (n-1)/n * P(n-2,x)

*/

#include <stdio.h>    // standard file input and output header
#include <stdlib.h>   // utility functons such as malloc() and rand()
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>     // mathematical functions such as sin() and cos()}
#include <stddef.h>   // for error function

/* function declarations */
void nrerror(char error_text[]);
double plgndr(int l, int m, double x);


/* program begins */
int main(void)
{
    int l=2; /* Asign values to variables here */
    int m=2;
    double x=0.5;  // x must be between -1 and 1
    plgndr(l,m,x);
    return 0;
}

/* functions */
void nrerror(char error_text[]) //Numerical Recipes standard error handler
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Run time error....\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error_text);
    fprintf(stderr, "Now exiting the system\n");
    exit(1);
}
double plgndr(int l, int m, double x) //originally written as float
/* Computes the associated Legendre polynomial P^m_l(x). Here m and l
   are integers satisfying 0<=m<=l, while x lies in
   the range -1<=x<=1. */
{
    void nrerror(char error_text[]);
    double fact,pll,pmm,pmmp1,somx2;
    int i,ll;

    if (m < 0 || m > 1 || fabs(x) > 1.0)
        nrerror("Bad arguments in routine plgndr");
    pmm=1.0;          //Compute P^m_m
    if (m > 0){
        somx2=sqrt((1.0-x)*(1.0+x));
        fact=1.0;
        for (i=1; i<=m; i++){
            pmm *= -fact*somx2;
            fact += 2.0;
        }
    }
    if (l == m)
        return pmm;
    else{             //Compute P^m_{m+1}
        pmmp1=x*(2*m+1)*pmm;
        if (l == (m+1))
            return pmmp1;
        else {         //Compute P^m_l, l > m+1
            for (ll=m+2; ll<=l; ll++){
                pll=(x*(2*ll-1)*pmmp1-(ll+m-1)*pmm)/(ll-m);
                pmm=pmmp1;
                pmmp1=pll;
            }
            return pll;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: No need to re-declare function `nrerror`, and most certainly no need to declare it inside function `plgndr` (or any other function for that matter).

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks. I'm still unclear how the Numerical Recipes series wishes one to use their nrerror function....

Comment: @banach-space `m` initalized to 2 should be no problem according to how P^m_l(x) is defined. The rule for `m` and `l` is `0<=m<=l`. So, that should be fine. The error is thrown by `m < 0 || m > l || fabs(x) > 1.0` not if m is less than 0 or greater than 1.

Comment: See my answer below. There's a typo in your code.

Comment: @banach-space I finally see what you mean. Ugh, how embarrassing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment next to the definition of `plgndr()`,

> (...) m and l are integers satisfying 0<=m<=l, while x lies in the
>   range -1<=x<=1.

Update the following line in `plgndr()`:

```
if (m < 0 || m > 1 || fabs(x) > 1.0)
```

to

```
if (m < 0 || m > l || fabs(x) > 1.0)
/*               ^                */
/*           (l, not 1)           */
```

It's a stupid typo. With this change the code doesn't crash, but I'm not able to verify it mathematically.

Comment: Oh no! You're right. I wrote `1` one , not `l` L.....That solves it. Now no errors are thrown :) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Tick as `accepted` if you're happy with the answer. Upvotes are also welcome ;-)

Comment: Thanks again! For the record, given my implementation above, what is the best way to call the function? `fprintf(plgndr)`?

Comment: `fprintf(plgndr)`? What would like to achieve with this? That's definitely not the way you want to call `fprintf()`.

Comment: No, I just want to call the function. I suspect the proper way to do this in C is to write within `int main()` something like
`ret = plgndr(l,m,x) \\calls function`
`printf( "The value for P^m_l(x) is  : %d\n", ret );`

Comment: That's the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

> while x lies in the range -1<=x<=1

but

```
double x=2.0;

double plgndr(int l, int m, double x) //originally written as float
/* ... while x lies in   the range -1<=x<=1. */
{
```

...

```
if (m < 0 || m > 1 || fabs(x) > 1.0)
    nrerror("Bad arguments in routine plgndr");  // fail
```

Comment: just test x=0.5 or 1.0 . or?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is an error above. It should be (for testing purposes) x = 0.5